# Validar DV de agência e conta da caixa Econômica federal

Tags: algoritmo

Não consegui encontrar nenhuma documentação que fale qual a conta que deve ser feita para validar o DV da caixa econômica federal, alguém sabe qual é a conta que deve ser feita ou aonde eu acho essa informação?

Consegui encontrar de todos os outros bancos menos da caixa.

Com base nas informações  que @aa_sp passou, ficou assim a conta.

```
public String getDVContaCaixaEconomicaFederal(String agencia, String conta)
{
    int[] multiplicadores = {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2};
    int soma = 0;
    String numero = agencia + conta;

    for (int i = 0; (i < (numero.Length) && i < (multiplicadores.Length)); i++)
        soma += (int.Parse(numero.Substring(i, 1)) * multiplicadores[i]);

    int dac = soma * 10;

    int m = ((dac / 11) * 11);

    int dv = dac - m;

    if (dv == 10)
        dv = 0;

    return dv.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Geralmente o dígito verificador é feito em módulo 11 base 2. Mas para qual que você quer, agência, conta, nosso número?

Comment: veja se nesse doc te ajuda: http://177.153.6.25/ercompany.com.br/boleto/laravel-boleto-master/manuais/Regras%20Validacao%20Conta%20Corrente%20VI_EPS.pdf

Comment: @aa_sp Muito obrigado.

Comment: vou colocar como resposta o trecho do documento que tem a regra

Comment: Se quiser criar novas tags, tenha certeza de ao menos acentuá-las adequadamente. Removi a tag [digito-verificador]. O que você quer aqui é saber o [algoritmo] utilizado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa melhorou assim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme encontrado no documento: http://177.153.6.25/ercompany.com.br/boleto/laravel-boleto-master/manuais/Regras%20Validacao%20Conta%20Corrente%20VI_EPS.pdf

as regras seriam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]